# Bluetooth on navigation bar works and doesn't work

Tags: xcode, bluetooth, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

[image]

Hi

I have an app that consists of 3 Navigation Controller in 1 tab bar controller.

The app has to connect and disconnect to bluetooth in every views.

So I added a button in navigation bar to connect to bluetooth function.

And use serial interface to connect bluetooth.

But the buttons in navigation bar sometimes work and sometimes not.

1. start -> V1 Connect Btn -> V1 Button -> V2 -> V2 Button : Doesn't
   work.
   (Button on V1 and V2 is functionally same, sending "s" to connected device)
2. start -> V2 -> V1 Connect Btn -> V2 -> V2 Button : Works.
3. start -> V3 -> V3 Connect Btn -> V1 -> V1 Button : Works.
4. start -> V3 -> V3 Connect Btn -> V1 -> V1 Button -> V2 : Bluetooth disconnect
5. start -> V2 -> V2 Connect Btn -> V3 : Bluetooth disconnect

As I draw in image, The original app is consist of 3 views and only V2 has 
a navigation bar to connect bluetooth.

So When I have added navigation bar to V1 and V2, I copied a functions from V2 to V1,V3.

Here are some common codes from views3.

```
import UIKit
import Charts
import CoreBluetooth
import QuartzCore

class GraphViewController: UIViewController, BluetoothSerialDelegate{


    @IBOutlet weak var barButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var navItem: UINavigationItem!
        serial = BluetoothSerial(delegate: self)
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @IBAction func barButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if serial.connectedPeripheral == nil {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowScanner3", sender: self)

// *********** V1 : "ShowScanner2, V2 : "ShowScanner ***************
        } else {
            serial.disconnect()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func serialDidChangeState() {
        if serial.centralManager.state != .poweredOn {
            dismissKeyboard()
            let hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: view, animated: true)
            hud?.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.text
            hud?.labelText = "Bluetooth turned off"
            hud?.hide(true, afterDelay: 1.0)
        }
    }

    func serialDidDisconnect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
        reloadView()
        dismissKeyboard()
        let hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: view, animated: true)
        hud?.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.text
        hud?.labelText = "Disconnected"
        hud?.hide(true, afterDelay: 1.0)
    }
}
```

I connected segue to navigation "present modally" and named if "Show Scanner1" and "Show Scanner3" after V2 segue.

I have thought segue isn't same(yellow arrow), it might makes problem.

But it is ridiculous thought.

How can I solve this problem?

Do I have to pass data seperatlly?

or is there a codes that I missed?

Comment: I haven't done iOS in a while but wouldn't that be better done in the AppDelegate so it is simply available all the time if that is the required functionality?

Comment: I'm new in iOS, So it might be wrong. But there is a swift file named "BluetoothSerial" and there is an protocol BluetoothSerialDelgate()  and extension BluetoothSerialDelegate(). I think this is the AppDelegate for bluetooth. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but with it in each view it's probably not getting 'passed around' but a new one created for each view which is why it seems to drop out. I could be wrong though, my skills aren't current. Wish I could help more...

Comment: @Steve you mean I don't have to set bluetooth in every view, right? I will do that way. Thanks for replying